# File#lstat.blksize comparison works in Ruby 1.6 but causes error in 1.9.3

Tags: ruby

Received this error from Ruby 1.93, the code is older (written for and runs on Ruby 1.6)

makeCores.rb:2136:in `block (2 levels) in same_contents': undefined method`>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Line 2136 is this
        if f1.lstat.blksize > 0

```
class File
  def File.same_contents(file1, file2)
    return false if !File.exists?(file1)  # The files are different if file1 does not exist
    return false if !File.exists?(file2)  # The files are different if file2 does not exist
    return true if File.expand_path(file1) == File.expand_path(file2)  # The files are the same if     they are the same file
    # Otherwise, compare the files contents, one block at a time (First check if both files are readable)
    if !File.readable?(file1) || !File.readable?(file2)
      puts "\n>> Warning : Unable to read either xco or input parameters file"
      return false
    end
    open(file1) do |f1|
      open(file2) do |f2|
        if f1.lstat.blksize > 0
          blocksize = f1.lstat.blksize  # Returns the native file system's block size.
        else
          blocksize = 4096              # Set to a default value for platforms that don't support this     information (like Windows)
        end
        same = true
        while same && !f1.eof? && !f2.eof?
          same = f1.read(blocksize) == f2.read(blocksize)
        end
        return same
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I can see that the lstat and blksize methods still exist.

Tried changing lstat to File.lstat the error message changed to:

makeCores.rb:2137:in `block (2 levels) in same_contents': undefined method`File' for # (NoMethodError)

How do I bring this up to date with Ruby 1.93?

Currently on Windows 7, Probably developed for Win XP.
Is there a replacement or better method to use than blksize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change:

```
if f1.lstat.blksize > 0
```

to

```
if f1.lstat.blksize && f1.lstat.blksize > 0
```

this should maintain the same logic, in a backwards compatible way: No blocksize provided *or* a zero value means use a default hard-coded value). The return value of `nil` for "not supported" was introduced after version 1.6

Documentation here for 1.6: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_file__stat.html#File::Stat.blksize

And here for 1.9.3: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File/Stat.html#method-i-blksize